# Create an ATL/MFC Environment to test an Armadillo process (C++)

Tags: c++, image-processing, matrix, atl, armadillo

I'm working on C++ Image processing with armadillo, and i want to create a debug environment to assess my Armadillo Pipeline performances and results. So I'm creating an VS2017 ATL project to do that.
I'm a bit stuck in converting CImage::CImage to arma::mat.

First, is the use of ATL a good choice? (I hope so ^^).
If it is, how can i convert CImage to arma::Mat?

Already thank you for your time guys.

Comment: Here is the example that found on SO, [conversion between opencv mat and cimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510743/conversion-between-opencv-mat-and-cimage)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your link shows the opposite process. Then i'm not sure the armadillo mat behavior is the same as OpenCV mat. Finally i'm not quite sure the parsing is the same, i mean rows or column oriented.
Or maybe i didn't get it^^.